# Getit Package Manager - Internal check error

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I use RAD Studio 11, but I can not install any package with the Getit Package Manager. I always get this error

> Internal check error

Can anyone help me?

[image: Install error]

Comment: You should contact Embarcadero Support.

Comment: Embarcadero servers have a lot of downtime! Have you retried over a couple of days?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is actually a support request in disguise.

Comment: Have you tried this yet? [Enabling GetIt Install Logs for RAD Studio Installation](https://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-july-getit-install-logs.html). Also, maybe this will help: ["Operation error, Internal check error" during Delphi 10.2 enterprise install](https://community.embarcadero.com/component/easydiscuss/operation-error,-internal-check-error-during-delphi-10-2-enterprise-install?Itemid=1)

Comment: Delphi Coder - Yes, I tried to install it many times, but I always got the same error window.

Comment: Remy Lebeau - Yes, I tried. The result is:

Wizard"...
[2021-11-18 18:39:01] [DEBUG] GetIt: Internal check error.
[2021-11-18 18:39:01] [DEBUG] GetIt: A problem occurred during the process.
[2021-11-18 18:39:09] [DEBUG] GetIt: Cancelling process...
[2021-11-18 19:04:02] [DEBUG] GetIt: Loading EULAS...
[2021-11-18 19:04:02] [DEBUG] GetIt: Installing Library "FireMonkey App Low Code

Answer (score 0):

First, configure `GetItCmd` to work in **online** mode.  The configuration is permanent, it shall run once only per RAD Studio installation:

```
c:\> GetItCmd -c=useonline
GetIt Package Manager - Version 7.0
Copyright (c) 2021 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Command finished with success!
```

Next, run `$(BDS)\bin\rsvars.bat` to setup RAD Studio environment:

```
c:\> rsvars.bat
```

Make sure the settings in file `rsvars.bat` were set to valid RAD Studio install location.  Run `rsvars.bat` every time before using `GetItCmd.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

All suggestions made are useless on Windows 11 pro having the same issue. Pinging the server is ok. So there is an issue with getit. An install on a win 10 os with latest updates works fine. Same as version 10.3 that works ok with win 11.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32155241)